# Intermittent SSL Error

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl

getting an intermittent SSL error on iOS.
I've turned off ATS, and we know this happens on OS versions < iOS9 as well

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=1011 "An SSL error has occurred and
>   a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a
>   secure connection to the server cannot be made.,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806 NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSUnderlyingError=0x1471b600

from our crittercism logs, seems like some users are able to replicate this. but we have not been able to

`Would you like to connect to the server anyway?`<-- this makes me suspect that there was an authentication challenge. how can i verify that?

`kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806` <-- does anyone know what this error means?

**Edit:**

`-9806` means `errSSLClosedAbort`
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55179.13/libsecurity_ssl/Security/SecureTransport.h

what can cause this? i don't think this is due to a spotty network because from our tracking tools, SSL connections to other hosts seem ok. and when a user hits this issue, it is re-produceable. seems to me like we need to inspect the failure with wireshark to get further information. but we have not been able to re-produce this. does anyone have ideas logging more information from apps in the wild to debug this?

Comment: are you sure the certificate is valid and not a self signed cert?

Comment: yes, we've inspected the certificates. i have to mention that this is reproducible by some of our users in the wild. but we can't reproduce it ourselves :/

Comment: do you have multiple servers serving the request?

Comment: can you provide the server name so we can try to hit it and look at the cert ourselves?

Comment: @allen yes, there are 3, and all 3 server certs have been set up correctly.

Comment: @jeremie sorry i can't do that

Comment: @tzl can you show us your DNS CNAME and IN settings? i suppose you have multiple IPs in the IN record.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this, I / we are now seeing a similar problem - intermittent SSL issues with no obvious smoking gun.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server SSL certificate is failing the built-in certificate validation. It is up to you to decide how to handle this and present a correct remediation to the user. This can happen for many reasons.

SSL trust evaluation is described in detail in [Technical Note 2232: SSL Trust Evaluation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html).

Comment: We did this command `nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://filename.hostname.net --verbose` as per this [post]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331623/ios-9-3-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-server-cannot) & every case got passed but we are still facing this Intermittent SSL Error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar errors in a few scenarios:

- The server was getting accessed via https://www.domainname.com instead of https://domainname.com (note the "www.") in which case because of how I signed the cert was making it invalid. (I later found how to make the cert valid for both addresses and used the virtualHost and htaccess to always push to www.jeremiedaigle.com)
- I had a load bearing server which was improperly setup. One of the servers had the cert, the other didn't.
- Last, I have also encountered this issue when debugging and trying to use a self signed cert because I was using a proxy (CharlesProxy) middleman to debug my requests. the Middleman cert, in this case had to be trusted by the device. You can do this by sending the cert via email and opening it on the device.